# Quickest way to migrate win application to web - .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, webforms

I have one win application with presentation layer done as windows forms.
Now I have request to transfer it whole to the web. Of course, this is a lot of work, so I'm wondering is it maybe somehow possible to achieve this without rewriting whole presentation layer to the web forms? I've heard that SAP has some technology to expose same forms in both win and web, so I'm wondering now how did they do it, and is it possible to somehow do this with C#?

I'm in a delicate situation where I have to transfer win client application to web as quickly as possible, disregarding performance or other issues, with as little effort as possible.

I'm using .NET framework (C#), and I should transfer this to ASP.NET.

EDIT: If I transform my win forms to win controls, can I then host them in IE? Maybe this could be fastest way to achieve my goals?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the technical difference between .Net desktop application and web applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579259/what-are-the-technical-difference-between-net-desktop-application-and-web-applic)

Comment: I have changed question title - it's not a duplicate question, I'm asking if there is some way to achieve this.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem; what is the end goal? "Migrate Win app to web" is not an end goal, it is an activity. Why do they want to perform that activity? What is it about the Win app that is not working? Why do they think a web app will make it work?

Comment: Everything is fine with WIN application, it works well. Client is stubborn, they think that they will have less work administering web application then win. Offering autoupdate feature for WIN application didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the obvious technical problems and limitations, there are a whole host of other reasons that applications designed for the desktop need to be *completely re-written* as web applications. Rich client applications simply should not and cannot work the same way as web applications.

Or, to put things another way: You can put wheels on your mama, but that doesn't make her a bus.

You're not doing anyone any favors by trying to "port" the app over as quickly as possible. It's going to be somewhere between "difficult" and "downright infuriating" to use, not the position anyone wants their software to fall into. Yes, it's a lot of work. But no, it's not optional.

Comment: In normal situations I wouldn't ask this question since I have enough experience and knowledge regarding limitations and differences of win and web technology. But, my situation is now very complicated since I have one month time to migrate win application to web, which we developed for 2 years. So, the question is: Is it possible, disregarding performance and other issues, and if it is - how?

Comment: @buhtla: No, it's not possible. Pass that message on to the client. The next best option is using a service like [GoToMyPC](http://www.gotomypc.com/) to run the desktop software on a machine remotely over the Internet.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer. The business and data layer MUST be reused. 'Only' the UI layer should be written from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Cody. Nothing will compare to a full rewrite of you application.

**But:** If you wish to keep your winforms application as it is, you can deploy it in a Windows Server environment, and provide access to it using Remote Desktop (aka Terminal Services) through a **HTML 5 Client**.

Advantages of a [HTML 5 Rdp Client](https://www.google.com/search?q=HTML%205%20Rdp%20Client):

- Zero client installation - you will just pass the addess to the server, just like a web page;
- Will work on any browser supporting HTML 5 (that is, you can run in PC's, Tablets and latest smartphones);
- Your application may need some UI adaptation, but the code will mostly be untouched.

There is one you can try for free (one concurrent access a time):

[www.remotespark.com](http://www.remotespark.com/)

*PS: Again, it may not be the perfect solution, but it delivers. In our company, we've been pointing this solution to our customers recently, and it is proven to be a great shot so far.*

Answer (score 0):

You can do some of this with WPF/silverlight but there is no want to host a windows form on the web.

Comment: IE can host WinForms .NET assemblies.

Comment: If I create winforms controls, can I host them in IE? Maybe this can be the dirty approach?